# How do you create web pages via the Stores/Content API in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

The [API Documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/content) states that the Content API can be used to:

> Edit and publish blog posts and **web pages**, improve SEO, and drive traffic to stores.

I'm working on migrating a site from a different platform onto BigCommerce. I was able to migrate all of the blog posts fairly easily using the API, but **the documentation for the web pages resource is completely missing.**

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This API endpoint doesn't currently exist. It is, however, in progress. I don't have an available ETA to provide around this. This wording on the docs is misleading.